# Argparse to denote time period, in hours or days

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to write an argument (for argparse) in which, I am trying to define the inputs in terms of hours or days.

For example:

```
def setup_args():
    ....
    parser.add_argument(
        "--time",
        type=str,
        help="Define the time period (only hours or days). Eg. 3h or 3d"
    ) 

def time_input(user_input):
    if user_input.endswith('h'):
        ...
        # using datetime module to forward current time X hours later
    elif user_input.endswith('d'):
        ...
        # I may specify it to a max 2 days.
        # using datetime module to forward current time X days later
```

While the function I wrote works, I am wondering if there is a better way to approach this, or is using `endswith` the only way to go?

Comment: I'd probably define two argparse arguments, `--hours` and `--days`.

Comment: You could use user_input.lower().endswith('h') to allow the user to enter upper or lowercase characters.

Comment: @OregonJim they're trying to do this through arguments on the command line. User input through the console doesn't seem like the way to go.

Comment: @AdamSmith That sounds like an idea too! I am throwing my question out to see if it is possible to combine these 2 arguments into 1...

Comment: @AdamSmith, I know that.  it works in both cases.

Comment: @OregonJim I guess I don't know what you're advocating for then? That appears to be a different solution entirely.

Comment: @AdamSmith, his question was "is there a better way".  If you don't understand, then lets move the discussion somewhere else.

Comment: @OregonJim ah I did misunderstand. I thought you were advocating for taking input from stdin. Note that modern Python allows for `str.casefold` which is a bit more (human-)language agnostic to do case insensitive compares.

Comment: @AdamSmith - yes, but casefold() also has unintended side effects, such as changing the length of the string.

Comment: @OregonJim ehhh but that's not really interesting here.

Answer (score 3):

**[Maya](https://github.com/kennethreitz/maya#maya-datetimes-for-humans)** might work for you:

```
>>> maya.when("in 1H").datetime()
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 27, 22, 16, 42, 371621, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> maya.when("in 1 day").datetime()
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 21, 16, 42, 371621, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

You may even specify arbitrary time values and not limit to only hours or days, which causes your app to be even more flexible:

```
>>> maya.when("now").datetime()
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 27, 21, 20, 7, 409348, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> maya.when("in 1 hour 2 minutes").datetime()
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 27, 22, 22, 7, 825372, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

P.S. Maya is powered by [dateparser](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser). Although you can use dateparser straight out of the bat to handle everything, I think Maya will prove more useful.

Comment: I'm not sure adding a new dependency is the best way to handle this case, but it's *a* solution for sure and I didn't know about Maya until your answer. It looks cool!

Comment: @AdamSmith Thank you! Although it might not be the best, I believe it makes it cleaner & more flexible. This is exactly what dependencies are for :-)

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned by @AdamSmith, are there any other ways (pythonic forms) instead of installing something new just so to get things going?

Answer (score 2):

A function like this, can be used as a `type` in `argparse`.  It could also be used after parsing:

```
def period(astr):
    if astr.lower().endswith('h'):
        units = 'timedelta64[h]'
    elif astr.lower().endswith('d'):
        units = 'timedelta64[D]'
    else:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('wrong time units')
    return np.array(astr[:-1], dtype=units)
```

I defined it to return a `numpy` `timedelta64` array, in part because I'm more familiar with it than with the Python `timedelta`, and it is easy to specify the time units:

```
In [249]: period('4h')
Out[249]: array(4, dtype='timedelta64[h]')
In [250]: period('3d')
Out[250]: array(3, dtype='timedelta64[D]')
```

`tolist` will extract it from the array and return a `timedelta` object.

```
In [251]: period('3d').tolist()
Out[251]: datetime.timedelta(3)
In [253]: period('3h').item()
Out[253]: datetime.timedelta(0, 10800)
```

The function could be changed to work with `timedelta` directly.

A parser could be:

```
In [239]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [240]: parser.add_argument('--time', type=period, help='time delta');
```

testing:

```
In [241]: parser.parse_args('--time 3d'.split())
Out[241]: Namespace(time=array(3, dtype='timedelta64[D]'))
In [255]: parser.parse_args('--time 4h'.split())
Out[255]: Namespace(time=array(4, dtype='timedelta64[h]'))
```

errors:

```
In [256]: parser.parse_args('--time 4m'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--time TIME]
ipython3: error: argument --time: wrong time units
In [257]: parser.parse_args('--time 4.34d'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--time TIME]
ipython3: error: argument --time: invalid period value: '4.34d'
```